# How to handle the socket error exception in python while checking the status of list of domains through a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, try-catch, serversocket

Iam checking the status of host ip for a list of domain using the socket.gethostbyname lib. So i have a domain list which iam iterating through a loop to get the respective ip for each and verifying those against list of IP.

while iterating through the domain list, if the socket couldn't return the IP for any of domain, it throw the exception error and stop checking the status for remaining domains from the list

```py
def verifY_And_get_Server_status():
    domains = ['a.com','b.com','c.com']
    ipList=['ip1','ip2','ip3']
    print("List of domins",domains)
    try:
        for value in domains:
            ip =get_HostName(value)
            print("IP of the domain ",ip)
        if ip in iplist:
              print('ip found', ip)
            else:
              print('Ip is not listed', ip)


    except ConnectionError as e:
        print("Error due to ")



def get_HostName(domainName):
    try:
        domain_ip = socket.gethostbyname(domainName)
        print("Domain IP is",domain_ip)
        return domain_ip

    except ConnectionError as e:
        print("Error log",e)


#Error iam getting
domain_ip = socket.gethostbyname(domainName)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Expected: i need to get the status of the domain as follows: if the socket returns the ip, the if condition should show the ip and if the socket didn't return the ip, it also should show the ip and the reason as message. And the loop should not stop checking the remaining domain names.

Actual: While iterating the loop, suppose if the socket couldn't return the ip for the domain 'a.com' due to connection error or down status, it throw the exception error and the loop stop checking status for remaining domain from the list.

Appreciate if any one can help on this?